# BerkeleyDB doesn't store files

Tags: c, put, berkeley-db

I am starting to use BerkeleyDB. I wrote the following method to insert values to the database:

```
void Put(int key, int value){
    DB *dbp;
    int ret;

    if((ret=db_create(&dbp,NULL,0))!=0){
        fprintf(stderr,"db_create failed: %s\n",db_strerror(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    ret=dbp->open(
        dbp,
        NULL,
        "berkeley.db",
        NULL,
        DB_BTREE,
        DB_CREATE,
        0
    );

    DBT bin_key, bin_value;
    memset(&bin_key,0,sizeof(DBT));
    memset(&bin_value,0,sizeof(DBT));

    bin_key.data=&key;
    bin_value.data=&value;

    bin_key.size=sizeof(int);
    bin_value.size=sizeof(int);

    if((ret=dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &bin_key, &bin_value, DB_NOOVERWRITE))!=0){
        printf("Put failed");
    };
    return;
}
```

After calling the `Put()` method, I get no errors. Dumping the database with the tool `dump_db berkeley.db` gets the database. It has been created, but still there are no values in the database.

Any idea?

Comment: You never check `ret` after `open()`...?

Comment: I have checked with the debugger. In both cases, it was 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't close your database before exiting your program, you might want to do that, for example, at the end of your `Put()` function:

```
if(dbp->close(dbp, 0)) != 0)
{
    printf("Close failed\n");
}
```

It might be that the data you put into your database is only added to the cache and not written to disk. In this case the function [`close()`](http://pybsddb.sourceforge.net/api_c/db_close.html) needs to be called in order to flush your data to disk:

> ## Description
>
> The `DB->close` function flushes any cached database information to disk, closes any open cursors, frees any allocated resources, and closes any underlying files. Because key/data pairs are cached in memory, failing to sync the file with the `DB->close` or `DB->sync` function may result in inconsistent or lost information.